# ggarrange with common legend produces extra blank plot in markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, rnotebook, ggpubr

I am using R Notebooks and have a chunk with some code for arranged histograms. When I use a common legend it produces an extra empty plot, which looks terrible in the rendered html file. This phenomenon disappears without a shared legend, but the plot looks terrible since they are not of the same size. Is there any way to stop it from producing an extra empty graph?

[image: Notebook chunk output]

and the code being used in the chunk

````
 ```{r}

ggarrange(

gghistogram(data, title="MOTIVATION SCORES", x="MOTIVATION", y="..density..", 
add_density=TRUE, add = "median", rug = TRUE, bins=15, color="#69c8ECFF", 
fill="#69c8ECFF") , 


gghistogram(data, title="MOTIVATION BY AGE GROUP", x = "MOTIVATION", 
y="..density..", add_density=TRUE,
          add = "median", rug = TRUE, bins=15,
          color = "AGE_GROUP", fill = "AGE_GROUP",
          palette = c("#69c8ECFF", "#E762D7FF")
          )

, legend = "bottom" 
, common.legend = TRUE

)
```
````

Comment: Could you share the output of `dput(data)` ? It would be easier to help you

Comment: I see the same thing when I use mtcars data.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: If you run the 2nd block below as a block of code in an rmarkdown document, it still generates the extra blank plot. If you run each line of the 2nd block manually (i.e. one at a time) it generates just the single desired plot. I think this still counts as a solution though because even running the first code block one at a time results in the extra blank plot.

This seems to reproduce the problem when run in an rnotebook:

```
p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
    geom_point()
p2 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = drat, y = vs)) +
    geom_point()
ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom", labels = c("A", "B", "C"))
```

If instead I assigned the `ggarrange` object to p, then the problem goes away:

```
p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
    geom_point()
p2 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = drat, y = vs)) +
    geom_point()
p = ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom", labels = c("A", "B", "C"))
p
```

No idea why. Highly unsatisfactory for me, but it seems to work.

Comment: if you are creating the plots with ggplot syntax, I'd recommend using the patchwork package instead of ggarrange.

Comment: if `p` is in a separate code chunk, then no blank plot is produced

Comment: This is now fixed in the latest dev version of ggpubr package, which can be installed using `devtools::install_github("kassambara/ggpubr")`

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the problem by opening a null pdf device

```
p1 <-gghistogram(data, title="MOTIVATION SCORES", x="MOTIVATION", y="..density..", 
add_density=TRUE, add = "median", rug = TRUE, bins=15, color="#69c8ECFF", 
fill="#69c8ECFF") , 

p2 <- gghistogram(data, title="MOTIVATION BY AGE GROUP", x = "MOTIVATION", 
y="..density..", add_density=TRUE,
          add = "median", rug = TRUE, bins=15,
          color = "AGE_GROUP", fill = "AGE_GROUP",
          palette = c("#69c8ECFF", "#E762D7FF")
          )


pdf(NULL)
res <- ggarrange(p1,p2, legend = "bottom", common.legend = TRUE)
dev.off()
res
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ggarrange` you may consider switching over to [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/). It does not have that "white page" issue and has a nice syntax.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=disp)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("plotA")
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=qsec)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("plotB")
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x="cars", y=hp)) + geom_boxplot() + ggtitle("plotC")

#/ Lets make P1 and P2 share a column, and give P3 its own column:
p1 / p2 | p3
```

[image]