# Why does ggbreak output an extra empty plot (RMarkdown)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, ggbreak

I am plotting a barchart with uneven frequencies, so that I make use of the `ggbreak` package. It works, but in my RMarkdown file, it outputs an empty plot in addition to the desired plot.
When knitting, the extra empty plot is gone, however.

MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbreak)

set.seed(1)
fruit <- sample(c("Apple","Banana","Pear","Plum","Dragonfruit"),
     100,replace = TRUE,prob = c(.5,.1,.1,.1,.1))
df <- as.data.frame(table(fruit))

ggplot(df,aes(x=fruit,y=Freq)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_break(c(20,50)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Here is the output:

[image: screenshot showing the output of R Markdown with one extra empty plot]

As you can see, it outputs the correct plot (aside from the x-axis scale issue at the higher end). As soon as I comment out the `scale_y_break` command, the extra plot disappears, which is why I believe `ggbreak` is causing it. I can't find any info on this, besides limitations of `export`, which I don't use.

What causes this behaviour, and what can I do to troubleshoot it? I often use RMarkdown for live demonstrations, and I would like the output to be clean.

A similar problem is asked in this question: [ggarrange with common legend produces extra blank plot in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48132699/ggarrange-with-common-legend-produces-extra-blank-plot-in-markdown) .
The answers did not help me.

The pdf-null answer does 1. not explain what it does, and why it is a work-around and 2. does not work in my case.
The other answer saving the plot and then adding the "problematic" code, doesn't work either, see below.

What I have tried:

```
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=fruit,y=Freq))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_y_break(c(20,50))+
  coord_flip()
p
```

and

```
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=fruit,y=Freq))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()
p + scale_y_break(c(20,50))
```